# How do you add 2 leading zero to the first column and 1 leading zero to the second column in an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have spreadsheet and I need a way to format the formula so that the first column have two leading zeros (000) and the second column to have one leading zero (00)
Minimum required code:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),,
   COUNTIFS(
    C2:C,C2:C,
    ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C))))
```

Comment: What do you mean?  You provided a formula that creates a 1 column array of `1`'s  and `` blanks.  `1`'s if there is anything in the column C including numbers, text strings, etc.  Is this your homework? How about an example of before and after.

Answer (score 1):

To format your columns with leading zeros, you can use the TEXT function in Google Sheets. This function allows you to specify a custom number format. This might work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),,
   TEXT(COUNTIFS(
    C2:C,C2:C,
    ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C)), "000")&":"&TEXT(COUNTIFS(
    C2:C,C2:C,
    ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C)), "00")))
```

Let me know if that works!